# Java wireless toolkit vs Net beans 7.2

Tags: java-me, netbeans-7, java-wireless-toolkit

I'm working on developing a mobile application using Java ME and would like to know 
what the differences are between using the Java Wireless Toolkit and Netbeans.

As far as I know both of them are used to develop mobile applications over Java ME
which one is better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Netbeans is IDE for not only JAVA ME Application ,but it also support for many other programming language. While Wireless-Toolkit is for Java ME Development purpose only.

However, even if you are using NetBeans you must install Wireless-tool kit to use Java ME Emulator from Netbeans.

Netbeans provides automatic compilation and syntax highlighting facility, while Wireless-tool kit doesn't have these kind of facilities.

Answer (score 1):

My personal preference is:
. WTK 2.5.2
. Ant
. Antenna
. Proguard
. Eclipse JDT

But I do not use LWUIT nor Polish.